# Would I have + what tense?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which of the following sentences would be correct (they're questions):

> Would have I gone through all this process had I got the opportunity to continue with the other option?

or

> Would have I gone through all this process have I had the opportunity to continue with the other option?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that better than either "got" or "had gotten" would be:

"Would I have gone through all this process **had I had** the opportunity to continue with the other option?"

or perhaps "**if I had had**"

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about a counterfactual situation, so this calls for the subjunctive, which technically speaking is a mood, rather than tense. When the subjective is used to discuss past event that didn't happen, "had" plus the past participle is used. In BrE, "got" is often used for the past participle for "get", but "gotten" is often considered the correct form in the US.

Writing "Would I have" instead of "Would have I", and putting an "of" before "this process" would also be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

What we are dealing with in this particular case is called- inversion of conditional sentences, in your case, the third conditional. Would I have gone through all this process had I got the opportunity to continue with the other options ?